# Why does python addition of 2 integers result in the two numbers being put together rather than added?

Tags: python

I am having a problem with my addition. The way I set it up is to take a problem (ex 5+3) and assign each number to a variable. I converted them to integers using int() but when I run my script it would come back as 53. Does anyone know a solution?
I am very new to python so my code is a mess.

```
    string = (pr)
    new_string = string.replace("+", " " )
    txt = (new_string)
    x = txt.split(" ")
    a,b = x
    int(a)
    int(b)
    print (a + b)
```

Comment: `"hello" + "world" == "helloworld"` ... `"2" + "3"   == "23"`  ... `2 + 3 == 5`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing type using str() and int()...how it works](/q/46706993/90527)

Answer (score 3):

Because `int(a)` does not change `a`, the generated integer number becomes an unused temporary variable. So `a` is still of a string type.

You need to use `a=int(a)` as well as next line `b=int(b)`